# How to load a url from adaptive card open url action into a teams channel website tab

Tags: microsoft-teams

I added a Website Tab ([1](http://davidgiard.com/2019/01/27/AddingAWebsiteTabToAMicrosoftTeamsChannel.aspx)) to a Microsoft Teams Channel with URL as *www.example.com*. I copied a link to the tab ([2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-a-link-to-a-tab-in-teams-9348ec0d-7e3e-4396-885c-474241c58849)) as *More option ... > Copy link to tab*. Then I am posting adaptive cards with open url action ([3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions?tabs=json#adaptive-cards-actions)) with copied teams tab url as link. Now if I click card action button, the teams channel tab is opening with default URL  *www.example.com*.

**Question:** Is it possible to open a sub URL say *www.example.com/123* in the channel Tab when I click the adaptive card action button? Teams deep links [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links) does not mention how to do this.

<sub>Of lesser importance is that, the URL I get by copy link to tab is of format: teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/19%3Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40thread.tacv2/tab%3A%3Axxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx?groupId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&tenantId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do this out of the box because you're not passing a 'url' to the tab, you are just instructing Teams to load that particular tab, with whatever you want to show. A way to get this behaviour that you want is to create your own tab, which can host an iframe, and then your tab can be called using deep link syntax, where you can encode certain instructions (e.g. 'open this sub path in the iframe').